# Using regex to get the string between each back slash

Tags: c#, regex

I want the content between the '\' back slash in a regex group.

```
C:\\Development\\TestEnvironment\\VIdeo\MyVideo.mp3
```

Comment: It should be possible to _split_, no?

Comment: I know but I want to use REGEX

Comment: I dont know. Thats the reason I posted this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're [hell-bent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hell-bent) on using regex:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // ... Input string.
    string input = "C:\Development\TestEnvironment\VIdeo\MyVideo.mp3";

    // ... One or more digits.
    Match m = Regex.Match(input, "(?i)(?x)\\\\([\\w\\.]+)");

    // ... Write value.
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing to add — If the path has spaces in it use `\\s\\w\\.` inside the square brackets.

Answer (score 5):

```
string path = @"C:\Development\TestEnvironment\VIdeo\MyVideo.mp3";
var split = Regex.Split(path, "\\\\");
```

But...

```
var split = path.Split('\\');
```

Accomplishes the same result and is <strike>*probably*</strike> faster.

Ran each of these 1 million times each through 32 iterations, and got these results. The numbers are ElaspedTicks from `StopWatch`.

```
Regex: 12707294.90625
Split:  3360008.8125
```

Obviously this is probably a non-issue if it runs only every now and then, but if that's not the case, I would *strongly* consider just `String.Split()`.